# Transpose and Sum array Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data in Gooogle Sheets:

[image]

I want to transpose and sum the rows in an array formula?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3FcZicBP2I1anMyUdFfWscfETOuREGewPr_HSqbQY0/edit#gid=284528632

[image]

How I can achieve this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B13:F30,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,scan(,filter(z,z<>""),lambda(a,c,a+c)))))
```

[image]

Comment: try: `=let(a,byrow(B13:F30,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,scan(,filter(z,z<>""),lambda(a,c,a+c))))),index(if(len(a),round(a/C19,2),)))`